# laravel on cloud foundry setup - PDO problem

Tags: laravel, cloud-foundry

I am trying to put laravel on CF. I managed to push laravel onto CF.

but when I tried to run artisan migrate, I am getting the error

> In Connection.php line 120:
>
> Class "PDO" not found

I have tried to add the extension by creating a n extensions.ini file in the directory .bp-config\php\php.ini.d

contents for the extensions.ini are as below

```
extension=openssl.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=bz2.so
extension=zlib.so
```

but even after doing a cf push, the error is still there. a check with php -m the extensions are still not enabled

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mysqlnd
pcre
Phar
posix
random
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter

[Zend Modules]
```

I have also tried creating the file options.json in the directory .bp-config with the following:

```
{
    "COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR": "vendor",
    "WEBDIR": "public",
    "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_81_LATEST}",
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["gd", "pdo", "pgsql", "pdo_pgsql"]
}
```

but also no luck.

can someone help guide me on how to have these extensions enabled for php?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when pushing a laravel project, I used it like this instead of using .bp-config.

```
# cat .php.ini.d/extentions.ini 
extension = openssl.so
extension = pdo.so
extension = pdo_mysql.so
extension = pdo_pgsql.so
extension = mbstring.so
extension = bz2.so
extension = zlib.so
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).